# register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead

Tags: functions, sidebar, debug

I turned on my Debugger and got this error...

```
Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2705

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2705
```

I went to the line of code in question...

```
function _deprecated_function( $function, $version, $replacement = null ) {

    do_action( 'deprecated_function_run', $function, $replacement, $version );

    // Allow plugin to filter the output error trigger
    if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_function_trigger_error', true ) ) {
        if ( ! is_null($replacement) )
            trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );
        else
            trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.'), $function, $version ) );
    }
}
```

what exactly do I change here?

Thanks,
J

Comment: you need to identify which template is calling the deprecated function; could be functions.php of your theme or a plugin (?)

Comment: This mistake is probably done by old wordpress plugin **Sideblog Wordpress Plugin**

Comment: i fix this by removing Tabbed Sidebar Widgets plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your title:

> [`register_sidebar_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar_widget) is deprecated since version 2.8! **Use [wp_register_sidebar_widget()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget) instead.**

Somewhere in your Theme - in `functions.php`, or in a function included within `functions.php` - you're adding custom Widgets. Look for that code, and replace usage of `register_sidebar_widget()` with `wp_register_sidebar_widget()`.

PROTIP: Use the [Log Deprecated Notices](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/log-deprecated-notices/) Plugin to track down where the deprecated function call is being executed.

Comment: The Log Deprecated Notices really helped...but when I went to change this `register_sidebar_widget(array('WP-Ecommerce Search', 'widgets'), 'widget_wpecommerce_search');
 register_widget_control(array('WP-Ecommerce Search', 'widgets'), 'widget_wpecommerce_search_control', 250);` to this

Comment: `wp_register_sidebar_widget(array('WP-Ecommerce Search', 'widgets'), 'widget_wpecommerce_search');
 wp_register_widget_control(array('WP-Ecommerce Search', 'widgets'), 'widget_wpecommerce_search_control', 250);` it gave me these errors at the top of the page.....`Warning: Missing argument 3 for wp_register_sidebar_widget(), called in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce-search-widget/wp-ecommerce-search-widget.php on line 219 and defined in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 604`

Comment: `Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 607

Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 719

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-includes/widgets.php:604) in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/plugins/gold_cart_plugin/gold_shopping_cart.php on line 86`

Comment: That's a separate question (how to use `wp_register_sidebar_widget()`). Also: did you read the linked Codex entries? They explain function usage.